# Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE): Swift Only Receiving the Last String Sent by Arduino

Tags: ios, swift, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I found no matter what I sent in Arduino BLE. The swift end in iOS only receive the message. For example, in the sample code below. The swift always print out "Optional(“0703”)". Does anybody know the fix for that?

Arduino code:

```
void loop() {
  BLE.poll();
  delay(1000);

  flag = !flag;
  serialEvent_3(flag);
}
void serialEvent_3(bool flag) {
  
  delay(100);
  if (flag) {
    outgoingDataCharacteristic.writeValue("5678");
  } else {
    outgoingDataCharacteristic.writeValue("4567");
  }
  outgoingDataCharacteristic.writeValue("4567"); 
  delay(500);
  outgoingDataCharacteristic.writeValue("0703");
  
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    
    String response_str = Serial.readString();
    response_str.trim();
    byte value[response_str.length()];
    response_str.getBytes(value, response_str.length());
    outgoingDataCharacteristic.writeValue(value, response_str.length());
    outgoingDataCharacteristic.writeValue("1234");
    
    delay(100);

    //Serial.flush();

  }

  Serial.flush();
}
```

Swift Code:

```
  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    switch characteristic.uuid {
   
    case UartGattCharacteristicReceiveId:
      //print(characteristic.value ?? "no value") // this will be a value where you need to write function to interpret
      print("data received")
      
      
      print(String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: .utf8));
      break
    default:
      //print("Unhandled Characteristic UUID: \(characteristic.uuid)")
      break
    }
  }
```

Comment: How are you receiving data on the iOS side? Are you using `notify`?

Comment: @Paulw11 No, for bluetooth, I just uses its event handler "didUpdateValueFor Characteristics" to receive data from iOS side.

Comment: That is the delegate method that will receive the data but there are two ways you can trigger data to be received. One is to explicitly call `read` the other is to enable notifications on the characteristic. You will want to be using this, not explicit read

Answer (score 0):

If you configure Arduino BLE characteristic like this (BLENotify flag for notifications):

```
BLEStringCharacteristic outgoingDataCharacteristic(UUID, BLERead | BLENotify, 512);
```

Then you can subscribe to it on iOS side, right after discovering characteristics:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    // find your characteristic in service.characteristics
    peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: myCharacteristic)
}
```

After that it should receive update every time you call `writeValue` on Arduino BLE side.

This example on github may also help: [ArduinoBLE characteristic](https://github.com/alexanderlavrushko/BLEProof-collection/blob/cdecb5232bb97a31bbc8943f9c73fd2fd5866fd1/ArduinoNano33/BLEProofPeripheral/BLEProofPeripheral.ino#L38), [iOS setNotifyValue](https://github.com/alexanderlavrushko/BLEProof-collection/blob/cdecb5232bb97a31bbc8943f9c73fd2fd5866fd1/iOS/BLEProofCentral/BLEProofCentral/BLECentralViewController.swift#L288)